# Do I need to install kubectl after installing docker?

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes

Do I need to install kubectl after installing docker? Yet docker comes with its own version of kubeCtl?

I was watching [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/8h4FoWK7tIA?list=PLHq1uqvAteVvUEdqaBeMK2awVThNujwMd&t=245) and I saw that kubectl was installed after installing docker. Even in [the Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-windows) they say:

> Note: Docker Desktop for Windows adds its own version of kubectl to
> PATH. If you have installed Docker Desktop before, you may need to
> place your PATH entry before the one added by the Docker Desktop
> installer or remove the Docker Desktop's kubectl.

This, to me, seems to imply that it is not uncommon to install kubectl when you have installed one that comes with docker. Why is it so?

Comment: "not uncommon to install kubernetes when"...did you mean kubernetes or kubectl

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I have corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: cross post: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/12106/40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have different version of kubectl in certain scenarios. For example you may want to interact with a remote kuberneretes cluster from the same windows system with latest version of kubectl which may not be installed with docker desktop.

It's generally recommended to have a version of kubectl which matches with the Kubernetes API Server version.

Comment: Is kubectrl an acronym for Kubernetes controll?

Comment: It's `kubectl` and it stands for *KUBErnetes Command-Line Interface* @YulePale